# Sometimes I can't delete a folder without admin, but if I delete its entire contents first, I can. Why?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, file-permissions, administrator

I encounter this every now and then, usually when trying to uninstall drivers or something like that. The general sequence is this:

1) Try to delete a folder. Get "You need admin!" message. Even when I am admin and/or click the shield icon.

2) Enter the folder.

3) Select and delete the entire contents of the folder, barring any hidden files that I didn't get caught in the select. No prompt for Admin.

4) Leave the folder.

5) Delete the folder. No prompt for admin.

I must be completely misunderstanding the security model of window, because from how I understand things, this doesn't make any sense. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the permissions for a folder your unable to delete.

Comment: I will try the next time I encounter this problem, but it doesn't happen very often. I don't really uninstall device drivers very often :p

Answer (score 2):

which files are in this folders? Video files? Maybe the `DLLhost.exe` tries to load the thumbnails and this prevents you from deleting it.

You can also use [ProcessExplorer to search for open handles](http://www.usabilitydistilled.com/2011/02/how-to-find-out-what-program-is-locking-a-file-in-windows/) to that folder. So here you can see which files still use data from a fodler:

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a likely culprit. I'll check for this next time I see it.